# VSCode NodeJS debugging allow HTTPS

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, https, yarnpkg

I'm struggling with configuration of VSCode launch.json to run NodeJS server via yarn start -ssl command on HTTPS protocol.

My launch.json is:

```
    {
        "command": "yarn start --ssl",
        "name": "SienaFE",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "node-terminal",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/SienaFE",
    }
```

Which ignoress --ssl attribute. I would like to launch the server this way so I have the access to JS debugging in VS code as well as the terminal output in VS code.

However it launches server only on HTTP.

[image: VS code terminal output]

Can anyone help me with configuration to run NodeJS on HTTPS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in VSCode launch.json configuration, but in NodeJS package.json configuration of React-Scripts:

```
"scripts": 
{
    "start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start --ssl"
}
```

"start": "HTTPS=true react-scripts start".

For additional info: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/